# Duplicate primary key exception MSSQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, jira, auto-increment

I use `MSSQL server 2008` as a database for my web application (JIRA) , Few days back I had inserted some values through database . Now when I try to add values through the UI I get the following exception .

> com.atlassian.jira.exception.DataAccessException: org.ofbiz.core.entity.GenericEntityException: while inserting: [GenericEntity:CustomFieldOption][id,10815][sequence,7][value,TEST][customfieldconfig,10400][parentoptionid,null][disabled,N][customfield,10300] (SQL Exception while executing the following:INSERT INTO dbo.customfieldoption (ID, CUSTOMFIELD, CUSTOMFIELDCONFIG, PARENTOPTIONID, SEQUENCE, customvalue, optiontype, disabled) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) (Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_customfieldoption'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.customfieldoption'. The duplicate key value is (10815).))

I believe this is because the primary key is an auto increment value and I inserted this value through query . 
Can someone please help me with this . I guess resetting the autoincrement sequence will help.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps!  FYI, SQL Server uses what is called identity not auto-increment

```
-- First check what value is being used
dbcc checkident('tableName',noreseed)
-- Then you can "reseed" it to whatever value you want.  If you use 10815, the value that will be used is 10816
dbcc checkident('tableName',reseed,10815)
```

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer:

Try to modify the codes of your UI application such that it executes a SQL statement that DOES NOT include the PK column, dbo.customfieldoption.ID.

Long Answer:

Your UI application tried to execute the following SQL statement.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.customfieldoption (ID, CUSTOMFIELD, CUSTOMFIELDCONFIG, PARENTOPTIONID, SEQUENCE, customvalue, optiontype, disabled) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

The SQL statement above seems to include a value for the PK column, which is dbo.customfieldoption.ID. If auto increment is enabled for the database, then your UI application does not need to include a value for the PK column.

Try to modify the codes of your UI application such that it executes a SQL statement that DOES NOT include dbo.customfieldoption.ID. The SQL statement should be similar to the one below.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.customfieldoption (CUSTOMFIELD, CUSTOMFIELDCONFIG, PARENTOPTIONID, SEQUENCE, customvalue, optiontype, disabled) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the quick response , I found a document which provided an sql statement to reset the sequence id . I resetted the sequence id to a larger number than current largest (PK value) . this resolved the issue

link to the doc :https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=193299577

Regards ,
Mizan

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem a few days ago and [Mizan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075745/duplicate-primary-key-exception-mssql-server-2008/16077393#16077393) pointed me in the right direction.

### Why does this happen?

Jira doesn't autoincrement the unique `id` used to identify  custom field values, but stores the next unique `id` in a table named `sequence_value_item`.

That's not an issue when you add custom field values through the GUI, because the relevant `id` in `sequence_value_item` is updated in the process.

But if you happen to insert custom field values directly into the database, the value stored in `sequence_value_item` may become outdated so that the `id` of values added through the GUI conflict with the `id` of values created manually.

When that happens, you can't add any values to existing custom fields and Jira displays an error:

> `com.atlassian.jira.exception.DataAccessException: org.ofbiz.core.entity.GenericEntityException: while inserting: [GenericEntity:CustomFieldOption][customfieldconfig,17008][sequence,0][customfield,15508][parentoptionid,null][disabled,N][id,18214][value,somevalue] (SQL Exception while executing the following:INSERT INTO public.customfieldoption (ID, CUSTOMFIELD, CUSTOMFIELDCONFIG, PARENTOPTIONID, SEQUENCE, customvalue, optiontype, disabled) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) (ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk_customfieldoption"`

### How do I fix it?

To solve it, proceed as follows:

1. Determine the highest `id` in use by running this query:

   `SELECT * FROM customfieldoption;`

   and looking at the last entry (in the output below, the highest `id` is `18595`):

   ```
   id   | customfield | customfieldconfig | parentoptionid | sequence |    customvalue    | optiontype | disabled 
   -------+-------------+-------------------+----------------+----------+-------------------+------------+----------
   18595 |       15200 |             16701 |                |      195 | somevalue         |            | N
   ```
2. **Stop Jira.**
3. **Back up the Jira database.**
4. Increase the `id` stored in `sequence_value_item` to a value higher than the value found in step 1.

   The value in step 1 is `18595`, so I set the `id` to `19000`:

   `UPDATE sequence_value_item SET seq_id = 19000 where seq_name = 'CustomFieldOption';`
5. Start Jira.

(Tested on Jira 8.20)